Maximal solutions is defined on all $\mathbb{R}$
I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Let $F: \mathbb{R}^{1 + d} \to \mathbb{R}^d$ continuous and bounded, then for all $(t_0,x_0) \in \mathbb{R}^{1 + d}$ there exists some solution $\gamma: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^d$ of the ODE $x' = F(t,x)$ defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$, with initial condition $\gamma(t_0) = x_0$. Is this solution necessarily unique?

The approach used was, as F is continuos, by Peano's Theorem, to the IVP
$$ x' = F(t,x) \, , \, (t_0,x_0),$$
we have a solution, and moreover, we can use Zorn's Lemma to find a maximal solution $\gamma: (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}^d$ to this IVP.
Now suppose, by contradiction, that $b < + \infty$. Let $(t_n)_{n \geq 1} \subset (a,b)$ such that $t_n \to_{n} b$. As F is bounded, let M > 0 such that
$$ F(t,x) \leq M \, , \, \forall (t,x) \in \mathbb{R}^{1+d},$$
hence, for all $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$
$$ || \gamma(t_n) - \gamma(t_m) || = \left|\left| \int_{t_n}^{t_m} F(s, \gamma(s)) ds \right|\right| \leq M |t_n - t_m|,$$
so $(\gamma(t_n))_{n \geq 1}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R^d}$. Let $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}^d$ be the limit of this sequence. So again by Peano's Theorem, the IVP
$$x' = F(t,x) \, , \, (b, y_0)$$
has a solution $\beta: (y_0 - \delta, y_0 + \delta) \to \mathbb{R}^d$ for some $\delta > 0$. Then define
$$ \Gamma: (a,b) \cup (y_0 - \delta, y_0 + \delta) \to \mathbb{R}^d,$$
such that $\Gamma(t) = \gamma(t)$ if $t \in (a,b)$ and $\Gamma(t) = \beta(t)$ if $t \in (y_0 - \delta, y_0 + \delta)$.
$\Gamma$ is clearly bigger than $\gamma$ in the partial order of solutions of ODE's, so we found a contradiction with $\gamma$ maximal.
But I'm struggling to understand why $\Gamma$ is well defined, i.e., why for all $t \in (a,b) \cap (y_0 - \delta, y_0 + \delta),$ we have
$$ \gamma(t) = \beta(t).$$
If F has the property of uniqueness of solutions, in particular, if F is locally Lipschitz on x, that holds, but it's not necessarily the case.
Thanks.
